# Google Sheets : lookup value for specific item at a specific date

Tags: google-sheets

I have a database of inventory levels at specific dates.

Items (SKUs), quantities and date are all updated by appending to a 3 column table.

I would like to transform this in a table.

Please see the sheet here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Mb1d0B4Sn53mW25XgEciTcQeVT2Zu8Sl68soGVN_MVY/edit#gid=0

How can I achieve that?

Many thanks

The only solution I can think of with my limited knowledge is to adapt the lookup arrow for each date column, which is far from ideal

Answer (score 0):

you may try (clear all the cells within `G3:J6`)

```
=makearray(counta(F3:F6),counta(G2:J2),lambda(r,c,sumifs(C:C,B:B,index(F3:F,r),D:D,index(G2:J2,,c))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize `QUERY()` function with `pivot` clause.

```
=QUERY(B3:D18,"select B, sum(C) group by B pivot D label B 'SKU'")
```

for full column as input, try-

```
=QUERY(B3:D,"select B, sum(C) 
where B is not null 
group by B 
pivot D 
label B 'SKU'")
```

[image]